# Delete row from related entity in many to many relationship in Doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have this entity:

```
class FabricanteProductoSolicitud
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedEntityTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\FabricanteDistribuidor")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fabricante_distribuidor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $fabricante_distribuidor;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\ProductoSolicitud")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="producto_solicitud_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $producto_solicitud;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Pais", inversedBy="fabricanteProductoSolicitudPais", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="nomencladores.pais_fabricante_producto_solicitud", schema="nomencladores",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fabricante_producto_solicitud_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="pais_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $paisesFabricanteProductoSolicitudPais;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\ModeloMarcaProducto", inversedBy="modeloMarcaProducto", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="negocio.fabricante_modelo_marca_producto", schema="negocio",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="fabricante_producto_solicitud_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="modelo_marca_producto_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $modeloMarcaProducto;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->paisesFabricanteProductoSolicitudPais = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->modeloMarcaProducto = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addModeloMarcaProducto(ModeloMarcaProducto $modeloMarcaProducto)
    {
        $this->modeloMarcaProducto[] = $modeloMarcaProducto;
    }

    public function removeModeloMarcaProducto(ModeloMarcaProducto $modeloMarcaProducto)
    {
        $this->modeloMarcaProducto->removeElement($modeloMarcaProducto);

        return $this;
    }    

    public function getModeloMarcaProducto()
    {
        return $this->modeloMarcaProducto;
    }
}
```

Through Ajax I made a request to a method that handle multiple values:

```
foreach ($request->request->get('items') as $item) {
    // delete row if it can be deleted 
}
```

In the code above, `$item['value']` holds `negocio.fabricante_modelo_marca_producto.fabricante_producto_solicitud_id` values, the idea is to delete each row from the related table (`fabricante_modelo_marca_producto`) by giving the `fabricante_producto_solicitud_id`, can any give me some help?

**EDIT: find the best approach**

Trying to find the best approach I made this piece of code:

```
foreach ($request->request->get( 'items' ) as $item) {
    $relacion = $this->get( 'database_connection' )->fetchColumn(
        'SELECT COUNT(fabricante_producto_solicitud_id) AS cnt FROM negocio.fabricante_modelo_marca_producto WHERE fabricante_producto_solicitud_id = ?',
        array( $item['value'] )
    );

    if ($relacion === 0) {
        $entFabricanteProductoSolicitud = $em->getRepository(
            "AppBundle:FabricanteProductoSolicitud"
        )->find( $item['value'] );

        try {
            $em->remove( $entFabricanteProductoSolicitud );
            $em->flush();
            array_push( $itemsRemoved, $item['value'] );

            $response['success'] = true;
            $status              = 200;
        } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
            $status = 400;
            dump( $e->getMessage() );

            return new JsonResponse( $response, $status ?: 200 );
        }
    }

    $response['itemsRemoved'] = $itemsRemoved;
}
```

}

Perhaps it has some issues since I'm writing yet and it's not tested but in this way I can know which item as deleted and which not, right? Is this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

First, retrieve all `$fabricanteProductoSolicitud` using a join to get their `$modeloMarcaProducto` in one query:

Secondly, go through the result and clear the `$modeloMarcaProducto` persisting the `$fabricanteProductoSolicitud` (this isn't translated in an access to DB, just marks entities as deleted for Doctrine).

Third, send the changes to the DB using a `flush`:

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $ret = $qb
                ->select("u")
                ->from('MyBundle:FabricanteProductoSolicitud', 'u')
                ->join("u.modeloMarcaProducto","f")
                ->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('u.id', ':ids'))
                ->setParameter('ids',$request->request->get('items'))
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();

        foreach($ret as $fabricantePS) {
            $fabricantePS->getModeloMarcaProducto()->clear();
            $em->persist($fabricantePS);
        }

        $em->flush();
```

This should remove all entities from the joined table with `fabricante_producto_solicitud_id` in `$request->request->get('items')`

Comment: this seems to be kind of exactly what we discuss [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27990289/719427) and then I ask the same, since `flush()` will try to execute all the queries or will rollback in case any fails, if I need to insert at least a very few records, how do I know which one was deleted and which ones no? See my edit for some info regarding this

Comment: @ReynierPM Hi there,I wouldn't do it that way, it's expensive in terms of queries. As I told you in that post, I'd use some of the events Doctrine provides in order to know which rows could have been deleted if there hadn't been any error. The answer is a bit long and I don't think it was what you asked here in the first place. I think it'd be better if you closed this question and opened a new one, don't you think? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097800/using-preremove-postremove-events-to-get-which-queries-can-be-executed-and-which

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way,

In Your Controller ajax action:

```
 foreach ($request->request->get('items') as $item) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $fabricanteProductoSolicitud = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:FabricanteProductoSolicitud')->find($item['value']);
    $modeloMarcaProductos = $fabricanteProductoSolicitud->getModeloMarcaProducto();
        foreach($modeloMarcaProductos as $modeloMarcaProducto)
        {
            //echo $modeloMarcaProducto->getId();
            $fabricanteProductoSolicitud->removeModeloMarcaProducto($modeloMarcaProducto);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
 }
 // return response; or exit;
```

Hope this help to you.

I wonder for better answer from other users.