# DRY: how to use this code in several entities accross Symfony2 project? Traits?

Tags: php, symfony, lifecycle, traits

I have this repetitive piece of code that will be used in more than one entity in my Symfony2 project so will be fine to apply some kind of DRY, if it's possible of course, and I'm thinking in [PHP Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

```
private static $preDeletedEntities;// static array that will contain entities due to deletion.
private static $deletedEntities;// static array that will contain entities that were deleted (well, at least the SQL was thrown).

/**
 * This callback will be called on the preRemove event
 * @ORM\PreRemove
 */
public function entityDueToDeletion()
{
    // This entity is due to be deleted though not deleted yet.
    self::$preDeletedEntities[] = $this->getId();
}

/**
 * This callback will be called in the postRemove event
 * @ORM\PostRemove
 */
public function entityDeleted()
{
    // The SQL to delete the entity has been issued. Could fail and trigger the rollback in which case the id doesn't get stored in the array.
    self::$deletedEntities[] = $this->getId();
}

public static function getDeletedEntities()
{
    return array_slice(self::$preDeletedEntities, 0, count(self::$deletedEntities));
}

public static function getNotDeletedEntities()
{
    return array_slice(self::$preDeletedEntities, count(self::$deletedEntities)+1, count(self::$preDeletedEntities));
}

public static function getFailedToDeleteEntity()
{
    if(count(self::$preDeletedEntities) == count(self::$deletedEntities)) {
        return NULL; // Everything went ok
    }

    return self::$preDeletedEntities[count(self::$deletedEntities)]; // We return the id of the entity that failed.
}

public static function prepareArrays()
{
    self::$preDeletedEntities = array();
    self::$deletedEntities = array();
}
```

This is the code I have in mind:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
trait DeleteLifeCycleCallbacksTrait
{
    // write things here
}
```

But will be the Annotation applied to the entity? Is that fine? What would you do it to avoid not repeat the code?

**EDIT: Trying to find best approach**

Having some ideas from **@Cerad** user and because as docs says *Lifecycle event listeners are much more powerful than the simple lifecycle callbacks* then I'll start playing with them.

So, first, the purpose of this `Lifecycle Callbacks|Listener|Suscribers` will be store the ID of each persisted object so I can get it in somehow and send back to the view from the controller. As a simple visual example, lets said I send from the view to the controller this array of values `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and for some X reason just 1 ,4 and 5 was persisted (mean was complete delete from DB) to DB, right?

Lets said also that I'll use the event listener in `Producto` entity. So, whithout test and just getting code from examples, the code should be something like this for the `Listener`:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Entity\Producto;

class StoreDeletedIds
{
    private $deletedItems = []; 

    public function postDelete(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if ($entity instanceof Producto) {
            array_push($deletedItems, $entity->getId());
        }
    }
}
```

My questions|doubts around this are:

- Is the code above fine or doesn't?
- Is `$deletedItems` cleaned every time the listener is invoked by Doctrine?
- How do I return `$deletedItems` in order to catch it on the controller and send back to the view?
- Do I need to define a Suscriber too? Why?

This are topics new to me so I need some kind of advise

Comment: I wouldnt use trait in this case. Have you consider make a class for it ? Or a service instead ?

Comment: @SergioCosta no I didn't in fact I have no idea how to do it using a service, using a class I think you mean extend that class later from the entity itself, I'm right?

Comment: Look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html and try to understand how services works. If you have any question, let me know!

Comment: @SergioCosta I know how services works and how to build them in this case to this one I should pass the EntityManager for get access to it, what I don't know at this moment is how this will help me on the DRY side, what is the advantage to use a service and how to use it from Doctrine Entity itself

Comment: Doctrine and DRY is an oxymoron.

Comment: @dan-klasson what _oxymoron_ means? I'm not familiar with that term

Comment: @ReynierPM create an abstract class for that entities and extend it

Comment: @PeterPopelyshko Could be an option but my doubt in that case is where to include the `* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` annotation? In that abstract class or in the entity which is extending from the abstract class?

Comment: @ReynierPM if every entity which extends abstract class need it that add it in `abstract class` otherwise `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` add where it is needed

Comment: @PeterPopelyshko take a look to myself answer, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following **@PeterPopelyshko** comment this is the solution I come with, just define a abstract class `Model\DeleteLifeCycleCallbacks.php` and put the code inside:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; // not so sure if this is need here

abstract class DeleteLifeCycleCallbacks
{
    private static $preDeletedEntities;// static array that will contain entities due to deletion.
    private static $deletedEntities;// static array that will contain entities that were deleted (well, at least the SQL was thrown).

    /**
     * This callback will be called on the preRemove event
     * @ORM\PreRemove
     */
    public function entityDueToDeletion()
    {
        // This entity is due to be deleted though not deleted yet.
        self::$preDeletedEntities[] = $this->getId();
    }

    /**
     * This callback will be called in the postRemove event
     * @ORM\PostRemove
     */
    public function entityDeleted()
    {
        // The SQL to delete the entity has been issued. Could fail and trigger the rollback in which case the id doesn't get stored in the array.
        self::$deletedEntities[] = $this->getId();
    }

    public static function getDeletedEntities()
    {
        return array_slice(self::$preDeletedEntities, 0, count(self::$deletedEntities));
    }

    public static function getNotDeletedEntities()
    {
        return array_slice(self::$preDeletedEntities, count(self::$deletedEntities)+1, count(self::$preDeletedEntities));
    }

    public static function getFailedToDeleteEntity()
    {
        if(count(self::$preDeletedEntities) == count(self::$deletedEntities)) {
            return NULL; // Everything went ok
        }

        return self::$preDeletedEntities[count(self::$deletedEntities)]; // We return the id of the entity that failed.
    }

    public static function prepareArrays()
    {
        self::$preDeletedEntities = array();
        self::$deletedEntities = array();
    }
}
```

Then use it as follow:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Producto extends Model\DeleteLifeCycleCallbacks
{
    // entity methods and properties here
}
```

Comment: yes like this, also define `abstract` methods if you need to implement them in each of the classes.

Comment: @PeterPopelyshko for now I don't need that one but is a good point for any looking for something like this, thanks

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it not very object oriented.  Is Producto a DeleteLifeCycleCallback?  Probably not.  Building a class hierarchy based on "has" as opposed to "is" can cause problems with your domain model.  If it works for you then great but static arrays and methods are red flags.

Comment: @Cerad, is not working at all, I'm still fixing some issues because `$deletedEntities` never return the IDs even if they are deleted (persisted) from the DB but anyway, what are they a flag reds? Can you tell me what are your suggestions to improve the code and get a better OOP?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without knowing your use case.  I tend to avoid using entity call backs and would probably start out with an independent subscriber object: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events.  But again, I can't really tell from scanning your code exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Cerad what I basically needs is to get which IDs was persisted to DB and for that I call the callbacks. Take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097800/using-preremove-postremove-events-to-get-which-queries-can-be-executed-and-which where you can found better info, let me know if this clarify things a bit

Comment: @Cerad take a look to my edit, could you getting some clue or advice?

Comment: This might help with some of your questions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Answer (score 1):

## Don't

Business logic doesn't belog into entities.

Traits won't help you either, because while duplicating code is a bad thing, abusing traits is *imo* even worse.

I once wondered wether I should use traits and posted a question on codereview (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74195/56686). I have yet to stumble upon a valid use case for traits in my applications.

## Make a service

I advice you to make a service and put your logic there.
Documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Because you can't call symfony services from doctrine lifecyclecallbacks, you would have to drop those.

You might wan't to fire up your searchengine of choice to look for a step-by-step tutorial.

Comment: Why you mean this is part of the business logic? It's not, I think. I'm just trying to return which entities could be deleted and which not and not, I'm not using Traits for this but for repetitive code on a entity for example getter and setter for ID. In the other side, have you experience doing something like that? I hasn't and need some code as start point could you improve your answer with some?

Comment: ```I'm just trying to return which entities could be deleted and which not``` I consider this business logic that doesn't belong into the entity. Join me in symfony2 chat if you wan't to discuss this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68838/symfony2

Comment: I agree with this! An entity should only be a data holding object.